# window position far to the right

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

Whenever I  try to open a Browser, a Transcript or a Test runner window,
theese windows open far to the right, and are partially out of the work area.
I always need to manually move then toward the center of the work area.

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update: misread tags, so now answering for both dialects**

The default behavior for window opening is "cascade", which opens the window slightly to the right and down of the currently active window.

So if the current window is already too far right, the opened window will be opened even further right (so the position where you click in the world matters).

You can disable or change this behavior, however note that although it may not work the best near the borders, the default behavior is the most natural, as you already have mouse cursor close to the window.

### Squeak

World > Appearance > preferences... > windows > reverseWindowStagger

### Pharo

World > Settings Browser > Appearance > Morphic > Windows > Window position strategy

Comment: Thanks, I've messed up the system fonts.
After resetting them to default and then selecting demo/hi-dpi mode, all goes well.